# MSAcesss TabCtl - Which Tab did I click away from?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'd like to base an event when a user clicks AWAY from 2 of my 7 tabs.

I have no issue determining which Tab I clicked INTO, I'm curious if there is a simple systematic way to determine which Tab I clicked AWAY from?  TabCtl OnMouseDown did not seem to help.

Using variables like: Tab_old vs Tab_new should be doable, but feels clunky...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

While you can work with

```
 Screen.PreviousControl.Parent.Name  ''Last control clicked
```

I think for safety, you are better off with something a little more robust, because a user could click a tab control and then click the main screen before choosing the next tab.

Each page has a click event, which would allow you to keep track of the page chosen.